# My simple servlet is called twice, I dont know why

Tags: java, servlets

My simple HttpServlet is called twice everytime I invoke on my endpoint (i found out by using APM):
http://cdctst1j:15611/TomSampleServlet/TomSampleServletClient

Could you please help me to take a look?
It is very simple.

WEB-INF\classes\TomSampleServletClient.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public final class TomSampleServletClient extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        xxxx;
        xxxx;
    }
}
```

WEB-INF\web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>TomSampleServletClient</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>TomSampleServletClient</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>TomSampleServletClient</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/TomSampleServletClient</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: Are you running this from within an IDE?

Comment: How are you invoking that endpoint? Via a browser? Or curl/postman/other tool?